# How to pass a variable to the IXMLDOMDocument::save method in MSXML?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, msxml

everyone. I know Microsoft have given an example about the save method of IXMLDOMDocument like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd874226(v=vs.85).aspx

But when I changed the parameter of save to a variable like CString or char* instead of a constant, I got an exception in the save method like this:
"Unhandled exception in VisualADS.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation."
The exception position is:

```
#pragma implementation_key(76)
inline HRESULT MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument::save ( const _variant_t & destination ) {
    HRESULT _hr = raw_save(destination);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;
}
```

This is a MFC MBCS project in Visual Studio 6, here's my code, thx!

```
CString strFilePathName = ar.GetFile()->GetFilePath();
CComBSTR ccbsFilePathName(strFilePathName);
CComVariant ccvFilePathName(ccbsFilePathName);
hr = pXMLDoc->save(ccvFilePathName);
```

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Please, show how buf is declared

Comment: And please specify if you build for UNICODE or for MBCS

Comment: Sorry for the unclear conditions, this is a MBCS project in VC6, buf is a global variable. The definition is: char buf[255];

Comment: @hsluoyz Did you managed to solve the problem, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The variant you pass to `IXMLDOMDocument::save` has to carry a `BSTR`. If your project is an UNICODE one, there is great chances that you'll have no conversions to do, and no reasons to crash using weird attempts.

If you are in a MBCS project, things are different: you have to somehow convert the file name from MBCS to UNICODE before using it in OLE/COM. I suggest doing so using the `CComBSTR` class

```
CString strFilePathName;
[...]
CComBSTR ccbsFilePathName( strFilePathName );
CComVariant ccvFilePathName( ccbsFilePathName );
hr = pXMLDoc->save( ccvFilePathName );
```

Comment: Hello, I have changed the code to this, but still encountered the same problem: CString strFilePathName = ar.GetFile()->GetFilePath();
  CComBSTR ccbsFilePathName(strFilePathName);
  CComVariant ccvFilePathName(ccbsFilePathName);
  hr = pXMLDoc->save(ccvFilePathName);

Comment: @hsluoyz Update your question with your actual code, and update the error you get, if it's not the same.

Comment: At first glance, I don't see why you should have an Access Violation. Put a break point at the ->save call and inspect the ccvFilePathName local variable. The vt filed should be VT_BSTR (8)and the BSTR value should be a valid UNICODE string. Show what you get. Also, maybe give some explanation on what exactly "ar" is